# Territory lost through Vassal Inheritance - what should I have done?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm confused.

As the King of Aquitaine, I had a vassal Countess of Foix. Her heir was Count of a single county in France (both nations are Elective Gavelkind). I had a Vassal Inheritance Warning, which makes sense; when the countess dies, her title would pass to her heir, who would add it to his French title, that being older.

So I created the Duchy of Toulouse and granted it to my Countess of Foix. I figured that this way, when she died, both titles would pass to her heir, and he'd bring his French county to over to join his higher Aquitainian Dukedom.

But when Comtesse du Foix / Duchesse du Toulouse kicked the bucket, I lost Foix to France, and another vassal held Toulouse. Is this an effect of the succession laws? Did one title pass to one heir, and the other to another heir? Could I have seen that, and prevented it somehow?

Comment: ...later in the same game, France declared war on me. I managed to kill the King of France in battle, meaning all of France was inherited by HRE. Who then declared on me. I... think I might reload an old save.

Comment: What was your Crown Authority ? And France's ?

Comment: Mine is Medium; how can I determine the CA of another power? (You're thinking it was High, aren't you?)

Comment: I'm indeed thinking it was High, so Foix [couldn't leave the realm](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Crown_laws#High_Crown_Authority).

Comment: Right. Well, my current ruler hasn't changed a Crown Law, so presumably if I could push mine to High as well, I'd be fine?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I don't know what would happen. I guess the Comtesse's heir will have to choose the title he wants to inherit, and the other title will go to the second person in the succession line.

Comment: To view other realms Crown Laws you can switch to the De Jure Kingdom map mode. Then when you mouse over a Kingdom it will display their Crown Laws.

Comment: @Ealhad If both titles are under the jurisdiction of high CA, whichever one he inherits first will be the one he keeps.

Comment: I have to play that game again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Liege cannot lose an existing vassal due to him inheriting new titles UNLESS the inherited title causes his rank to match or exceed that of his Liege. The rank of the title held/inherited makes no difference. It's a question of who he was a sworn vassal to first. The Count in question was sworn to serve the King of France first. At that point, any new titles he inherits will be added to his demense within the Kingdom of France. The only exception would be if he inherited a Kingdom or Empire title, which could not be a vassal of the King of France, which would make him independent.

If your Kingdom of Aquitaine had High Crown Authority, that would prevent the French Count from inheriting. The title would instead pass to the next heir in line that was not currently a vassal to someone outside of your realm.

Aside from Crown Authority, you might have been able to have the French Count assassinated. It's possible the Duchess's new heir would then be someone that is not a vassal of the King of France. If you manage to murder enough people, you might even cause the Count's title to be inherited by your duchess, depending on succession laws, gender laws, family dynamics etc.